# dependant dropdown not populating

Tags: php, json, ajax, dropdown

I am trying to populate a drop down box depending which county has been selected the second drop down should populate with the provinces of the chosen county.

I don't understand why the second dropdown is not populating. I am getting a JSON response in the console so the PHP is correct.  I am sure it is something silly but I just cant see it. Thanks in advance.

**index.php page**

```
<?php
    include "config.php";
?>
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>dropdown</title>
        <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <script src="jquery-1.12.0.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            $( document ).ready( function () {

                $( "#country" ).change( function () {
                var countryid = $( this ).val();

                    $.ajax( {
                        url: 'getUsers.php',
                        type: 'POST',
                        data: {
                            countryid: countryid
                        },
                        dataType: 'json',
                        success: function ( response ) {

                            var len = response.length;

                            $( "#province" ).empty();
                            for ( var i = 0; i < len; i++ ) {
                                var id = response[ i ][ 'provinceid' ];
                                var name = response[ i ][ 'provincename' ];

                                $( "#province" ).append( "<option value='" + id + "'>" + name + "</option>" );

                            }
                        }
                    } );
                } );

            } );
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>


        <div>Country</div>
        <select id="country">
            <option value="0">- Select -</option>
            <?php 
                // Fetch Country
                $stmt = $conn->prepare('SELECT * FROM countries');
                $stmt->execute();

                while($countries = $stmt->fetch()) {

                $countryid = $countries['id'];
                $countryname_en = $countries['countryname_en'];

                // Option
                echo "<option value='".$countryid."' >".$countryname_en."</option>";
                }


            ?>
        </select>
        <div class="clear"></div>

        <div>Province</div>
        <select id="province">
            <option value="0">- Select -</option>
        </select>
    </body>
</html>
```

**PHP**

```
<?php

    include "config.php";

    var_dump($_POST);
    $countryid = $_POST['countryid'];

    $countryid = "CA";

    $stmt = $conn->prepare('SELECT * FROM provincestates WHERE countryid = :countryid');
    $stmt->execute(array(
        ':countryid' => $countryid
    ));

    /*
    echo "<pre>";
    echo "prov is:" . $province_array = array();
    echo "</pre>";
    */


    while ($province = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
        $provinceid   = $province['provincestatecode'];
        $provincename = $province['provincestatename_en'];

        $province_array[] = array(
            "provinceid"    => $provinceid,
            "provincename"  => $provincename
        );
    }

    echo json_encode($province_array);
```

Comment: What does `console.log(response)` return inside your success function?

Comment: Once you can get a response with the proper data structure, here is a working example. https://jsfiddle.net/hadxLser

Comment: the console says the payload is:
XHRPOSThttps://dev-roe-vti.org/idashboard/ajax/getUsers.php
[HTTP/1.1 200 OK 32ms]

 
Preview 
Response payload 

1

array(1) {

2

  ["countryid"]=>

3

  string(2) "CA"

4

}

5

[{"provinceid":"AB","provincename":"Alberta"},{"provinceid":"BC","provincename":"British Columbia"},{"provinceid":"MB","provincename":"Manitoba"},{"provinceid":"NB","provincename":"New Brunswick"},{"provinceid":"NL","provincename":"Newfoundland and Labrador"},{"provinceid":"NS","provincename":"Nova Scotia"},]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally got it:

Apparently JSON.parse is depreciated and I had to change it from  var json=JSON.parse( response ); to just var response = response

Thanks for all your help!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not overly familiar wit jQuery but it seems you need to parse the response using `JSON.parse` ( or native jQuery method ? ) and then you ought to be able to access the data OK. The following might point you in the right direction - or it might not as it is not tested...

```
<script>
    $( document ).ready( function () {

        $( "#country" ).change( function () {
            var countryid = $( this ).val();

            $.ajax( {
                url: 'getUsers.php',
                type: 'POST',
                data: {
                    countryid: countryid
                },
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function ( response ) {
                    var json=JSON.parse( response ); /* PARSE the data */
                    $( "#province" ).empty();

                    for( var i in json ){/* access using object notation */
                        var obj=json[ i ];
                        var id=obj.provinceid;
                        var name=obj.provincename;

                        $( "#province" ).append( new Option(id,name) );
                    }
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Hi RamRaider,
thanks for the quick reply but the dropdown still does not populate and it looks like the exact same payload I was getting before but I learned something new so thank you.

Comment: He doesn't need `JSON.parse`, `dataType: 'json'` parses it automatically.

Comment: @EternalHour - thank you for the clarification. As I mentioned I don't know jQuery but perhaps should have known ( had suspicions ) that jQuery was smarter than your average bear and that would have been covered. I learned something there though so thanks.

Comment: Like you I'm just here to help.